# JVM suddenly starts eating CPU and then releases it

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, tomcat

We have been facing a really weird issue with a Java Web Application running in several Tomcat Servers.

The issue is as follows:  From time to time (can be weeks or months), JVM process starts eating all CPU (High CPU Usage) for sustained periods of time, and it is necessary to restart the server in order to solve the issue.  Then the issue "jumps" to another server where the application is installed (the application is installed on 4 servers).

We've taken some Thread Dumps during the issue, I've tried to analyze those Thread Dumps, but I have not found something by now. Following URL contains the Thread Dump Analysis (I took several Thread Dumps, each 15 seconds).

[Thread Dump Analysis](http://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTcvMDkvOC8tLXBwNF90aHJlYWRfZHVtcF9TZXBfMDhfMTcudHh0Lmd6LS0xNS00NS00Mw==)

We don't see any unusual errors/issues at Tomcat/Application Logs and our Security Systems (IDS, Firewall) don't detect anything unusual (traffic, users, etc).

Garbage Collection is working fine.

This is the configuration for Java, OS and full command line for starting Tomcat.

jdk1.7.0_80
Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.57
CentOS release 6.3

2 Cores 
4 GB RAM

/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/java/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1256m -Xmx1256m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=10000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/java/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/java/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/java/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/java/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/java/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/java/tomcat7/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

I appreciate your help !!!!

Comment: When you reboot the first thrashing server, how long is the delay until the second server starts thrashing?  Can you provide some CPU usage profiles for a few hours before a server starts thrashing?

Comment: @WarrenDew usually just a few minutes after we restart the server to jump to another server.  Next time this happens I will be ready to take some CPU profiles using VisualVM or JMC, unfortunately, this does not happen often, so, It can take some time until it appears again.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Most likely there is a request that is handled poorly by your server and causes it to thrash.  Whoever is submitting the request resubmits it after your server restart, causing another server to thrash instead.  You request logs might help to identify the problem request, or you might want to put in additional logging.